# KKT stationarity condition

Tags: convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider the problem:
\begin{align}
\min_{x\in X}f(x)\qquad {\rm s.t.}\;\;h(x)=0,\;\;g(x)\leq0.
\end{align}
Assume that $X$ is closed and convex, $f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable and convex over $X$, and $h$ is affine. Also assume that the Slater condition holds. Define the Lagrangian as $L(x,\lambda,\mu)=f(x)+\lambda^Th(x)+\mu^Tg(x)$.

I am confused with the KKT stationarity condition of the above problem. If $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, I know that the KKT stationarity condition is $\nabla_xL(x,\lambda,\mu)=\nabla_xf(x)+\sum_{j}\lambda_j\nabla_xh_j(x)+\sum_{l}\mu_l\nabla_xg_l(x)=0$. Now, if $X\neq\mathbb{R}^n$, what shoud the condition be? I am thinking that it should be $\nabla_xL(x,\lambda,\mu)\in N_X(x)$, where $N_X(x)$ is the inward normal cone to $X$ at $x$, i.e., $N_X(x)=\{p\in\mathbb{R}^n:p^T(x-y)\leq0,\;\forall y\in X\}$. The overall KKT conditions are then
\begin{align}
x\in X,\;\;\nabla_xL(x,\lambda,\mu)\in N_X(x),\;\;h(x)=0,\;\;g(x)\leq0,\;\;\mu^Tg(x)=0,\;\;\mu\geq0.
\end{align}
I am not sure whether the above conditions are correct.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any version of the KKT conditions with this additional constraint $x \in X$.  One point is that "Slater's condition" would need to be something like there is an $x$in the interior of $X$ that strictly satisfies the nonlinear inequality constraints.  Otherwise, X might combine with the inequality constraints to produce a feasible set with the problems that can occur when the regular Slater's condition isn't satisfied.

Comment: In Luenberger, 'Optimization by Vector Space Methods', Chapter 9, Problem 5 is to show that for the problem $\text{minimize } f(x) \text{ subject to } G(x)\leq 0, \ x \in \Omega $ where $\Omega$ is convex (no other condition on $\Omega$ the condition is that there exists $z \geq 0$ such that $\nabla f(x_0) + \sum_{j = 1}^{n}{ z_j \nabla g_j(x_0) } \in (\Omega - x_0)^\oplus$, where $S^\oplus = \{y \in \mathbf{R}^n : y^Tx \geq 0 \text{ for all } y \in S\}$. There is a regularity condition on $x_0$, namely $G(x_0) + G'(x_0)h < 0$ for some $h$. (...)

Comment: (...) He does not treat the case with equality constraints. I believe this is the same as your condition?

Comment: @mcpca Yes, this is the same as my condition. Thanks a lot for providing the reference!!